# Why is Switching View Controllers Slow the First Time?

Tags: performance, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nsarray

I have a project with two view controllers. When I press a button, the other view is loaded. The first time I do this, the program pauses for a second as the second view controller loads. I have very little in the viewDidLoad method. After I navigate to the second view after the first time, the views are swapped in and out quickly. How can I remedy this/what am I missing?

Also, there is no slow down if I do not create the array in the viewDidLoad method.

Here's my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sound1", @"sound2", nil];

    self.listData = array;

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

And my button to load the second view:

```
- (IBAction)soundListButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Pressed!");

    BBRViewController * controller = [[BBRViewController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"BBRViewController" bundle:nil];

    controller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;


    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using segues? What's on the view? Have you done anything in `initWithNibName:`?  Are you testing on the simulator or device?

Comment: Are you using viewDidAppear method or ViewDidDisapear method in any of the two view controller?

Comment: nhgrif- The view contains a table and a button. This is on a simulator. initWithNibName I use here-                                                  (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: Prabhu - I tried using the viewDidAppear which helped some, but still had some lag